# .htaccess hide everything after root domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I need to hide everything after root domain. Is there are any way to do it for all links at once?

For example:

```
www.example.com/index.php?a=something&b=something&c=.... -> www.example.com/home/
```

I want to hide all url and leave just root domain so that no one could see all the parameters such as:

`?a=new&c=592412&d=...`

Comment: Stop using `GET` method to pass parameters to other page

Comment: You don't need to use htaccess for this. Just use `POST` method in form instead of `GET`.

Comment: mostly i'm using this in links, not in forms

Answer (score 0):

**GET** requests include all required data in the URL. Forms in HTML can use either method by specifying **method="*POST*"** or **method="*GET*"** (default) in the  element.

so, basically change from "get" to "post".

```
<form action="demo_form_method_post.asp" method="**post**" target="_blank">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: there are some situations that i can't use POST method, so i need to do something with url.

Comment: please specify the problem,

Comment: well i have a website which has menu. Each menu link calls different action like including php file into main index.php page (<a href="?a=new">) or sorting list items (<a href="?a=list&s=p">). Some links has about 5-6 parameters. So i want to hide everyting after ? (question mark) that no one can see all these parameters, just leave only root domain (http://localhost/, www.example.com) without index.php?a=edit&$c=123456 ...

Comment: href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/insert_new2?<?php echo $row->id; ?>"

Comment: admin is the file name controller folder that contain insert_new2 funtion. in the funtion you can do what you want.